# Call object method right after its construction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a class that, among its properties, has a dynamically loaded DOM elements. A very simple overview of this flow:

1. Window is loaded
2. Object of class `SomeClass` is created (With (2.1) some attributes, and (2.2) a DOM Element dynamically loaded using AJAX)
3. Something with these DOM element properties is done (transformations etc.) optionally

Like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){ // Step 1
  someObject = new someClass("element_id") // Step 2.1
  someObject.loadToDOMThroughAJAX(function(){ // Step 2.2
      someObject.optionalMethodAfterConstruction(); // Step 3
  }); 
})
```

Edit: The snippet for `optionalMethodAfterConstruction()` :

```
someClass.prototype.optionalMethodAfterConstruction = function(){
  var element = this.element.querySelector(".someClass")
  element.setAttribute("transform","translate(20,20)")
}
```

Edit2: Snippet for `loadDOMThroughAjax()`:

```
someClass.prototype.loadDOMThroughAjax= function(){
  obj = this;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET", "/path/to/html", true);
  ajax.send();
  ajax.onload = function(e) {
    obj.element.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
  }
}
```

However, when step 3 is executed, the DOM elements have not yet been loaded in step 2.2, which causes step 3 to fail because it relies on a succesful `document.querySelector()` call. The DOM element with class `.someClass` is loaded dynamically and should be present when that method is called, but it isn't. Manually calling the method does work.

I feel like I'm close, but I'd like to know how to properly do this and what I'm missing.

I can't attach this to the constructor itself because it should not be applied to every object, just some.

No jQuery.

Comment: `loadToDOMThroughAJAX` seems to have a callback, if that callback isn't working, you should post that function so we know what it does.

Comment: This is because `querySelector`
 is not live. try `getElementsByClassName` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code unless you show it to us.

Comment: @JLRishe I edited my code. (@adeneo)

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg You haven't shown us what `loadToDOMThroughAJAX` does, and that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @JLRishe See my second edit please :) Thanks.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg `loadToDOMThroughAJAX` never calls its callback function. How is that callback function getting called?

Comment: @JLRishe You're right, the answer below builds on this so I'll respond there in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second edit I see that you don't actually call the function you send as parameter in step 2.2.

```
someObject.loadToDOMThroughAJAX(function(){ // Step 2.2
  someObject.optionalMethodAfterConstruction(); // Step 3
});
```

But your function is as follows:

```
someClass.prototype.loadDOMThroughAjax= function(){
  obj = this;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET", "/path/to/html", true);
  ajax.send();
  ajax.onload = function(e) {
    obj.element.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
  }
}
```

You should also call the parameter as par of your onload function thusly:

```
someClass.prototype.loadDOMThroughAjax= function(CALLBACK){
  obj = this;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET", "/path/to/html", true);
  ajax.send();
  ajax.onload = function(e) {
    obj.element.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
    if (someConditionIsTrue) {
      CALLBACK();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the callback call within the method and place it in the `ajax.onload`. Works perfectly now! Learnt a lot about callbacks in the process. Cheers!